# Decrypting BitLocker and regaining access to Windows 8.1 after forgetting the local user account password

Tags: windows, windows-8, encryption, passwords

I am trying to regain access to my Windows 8.1 local account which I have lost the password to. BitLocker is enabled, and I still know the BitLocker password. I have attempted to use ntpasswd but it has no support for BitLocker protected installations.

I figured I will have to decrypt the drive and disable BitLocker first, but after looking through all the recovery tools, I found no option to do that. Trying the "change startup settings", restarting and entering the password, I found nothing very useful. Under additional options it brought me back to the same menu as before, and since I have entered the BitLocker password already, I've tried the command prompt.

All lines had to begin with X:\windows\system32>
If I recall correctly.
Entering manage-bde -off C:, it told me that BitLocker is not enabled on the drive.

What can I do to regain access to the local account?

Edit: I have accepted the fact that I can't do anything about my issue, I am not getting my data back, there is only one local account, not linked to anything. All I have is the BitLocker password and I can't do anything with that. Thanks for comments and answers.

Comment: You can't.  This was the one of the reasons I presumed you used full disk encryption.

Comment: If you can enable the built-in Administrator user that would allow you to change the password to your user account.  If the password you forgot is to that account then you are out of luck.

Comment: Why is it not possible? At least a third party tool should be able to decrypt it.

Comment: How do I enable it?

Comment: Bitlocker is a closed source solution.  I am not aware of a single third-party tool that supports it.  Besides your problem is there isn't a tool that supports a Bitlocker volume and allows you to change the user's password.

Comment: I suggest you do research on how to enable the default Administrator user.  How you do that is well documented and has already been asked on this very website.

Comment: [You can use this solution from within WinRE to enable the default `Administrator` user.](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/9650-built-administrator-account-enable-disable-windows-8-a.html)

Comment: @Ramhound WinRE still doesn't let me load hive from D: after using command prompt and regedit (the system still regards D: as locked). I have entered WinRE from BitLocker recovery after entering the password but trying to open command prompt from it still asks me to enter the recovery key, leaving me with no other option than "skip this drive". Is there really nothing I can do? Is it possible to enter WinRE from anywhere else than BitLocker recovery in my current situation?

Comment: You need the recovery key you were going to need that regardless

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the BitLocker Recovery Key handy?
If so, you can mount it in another machine and decrypt the drive, allowing you to do whatever you like to the user accounts.

See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766200%28v=ws.10%29.aspx#BKMK_AltPC

Comment: "When you unlock the BitLocker-enabled hard disk on the alternate computer, the only authentication operation available will be recovery. The hard disk will appear in the BitLocker Control Panel item with an option to unlock the volume using the recovery password or recovery key."  *This means the user won't be able to decrypt the drive just mount it on the new system*  Bitlocker was designed not to allow you to decrypt the drive on a new system.

Comment: But if I mount it, I should be able to access my data, right?

Comment: You can mount the drive **if and only if** you have the recovery key.  If you don't have the recovery key then you cannot mount it even if you have the password.  Even when you do mount it you have not "accessed" the local account just the data within the profile.  You also cannot.  *I suppose you could in theory load the registry hive on that system and enable the Administrator account that way.*  Seems a great deal of work when you have WinRE for exactly that purpose though.

Answer (score -1):

If the local account is your only option, then this answer won't help.  But there may be away to bypass the local account using another account on the computer.

Check all of the accounts on the computer - if you're lucky, there might be an admin account that isn't just local, but is linked to a domain (work, school, or a Microsoft-owned domain like outlook.com).  If you connect the computer to the internet, you could use such an account to *change* the password for the local account.

If the domain account belongs to someone else, either ask them to remotely connect to the computer, or request that they share their password.

If there's a domain account, but you also don't know that password, you're still okay.  Just contact your domain admin or use the appropriate website to change the password.  As long as the computer is connected to the internet, it should accept the new password.